# How to connect to postgres database in different project in openshift

Tags: postgresql, networking, sonarqube, openshift

I am trying to connect my sonarqube application with a postgres database that is created in different project but everytime it throws can't connect error .

I tried setting the network policy to allow connection requests only from sonarqube project but it doesn't seem to work . Referred below guide for the same .

https://blog.openshift.com/network-policy-objects-action/

Sonarqube from its project should be able to connect postgres database service created in different project within openshift

Comment: In case things have changed in some way since, instead of creating the resources yourself, try using ``oc adm pod-network`` command.

Comment: Can we restrict the sonarqube project to use only the DB service created for them in postgres project assuming there are multiple Db services created within the postgres project for different projects.

Comment: With ordinary pod networks I don't think so. You would likely need a service mesh such as Istio to get more fine grained control.